# Two inputs of the same network error in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to have a TensorFlow model that joins the representation and the classification parts separately. However, my classifier uses two inputs that come from the same representation network and the time I coded this architecture I received the error: "The list of inputs passed to the model is redundant. All inputs should only appear once.". This is the code I have.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def representation():
    inp = tf.keras.Input(shape=[100, 300])
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(300, 10, 1, 'same')(inp)
    output = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(300, 10, 1, 'same')(x)
    return tf.keras.Model(inp, output)

def classifier():
    inp1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=[100, 300])
    inp2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=[100, 300])
    output = tf.keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid')(inp1+inp2)
    return tf.keras.Model([inp1,inp2], output)

repre = representation()
cla = classifier()

model = tf.keras.Model([repre.input, repre.input], cla([repre.output, repre.output]))
```

I used two representations like `tf.keras.Model([repre1.input, repre2.input], cla([repre1.output, repre2.output]))` and it works but, the representations come from different networks.

Comment: Why do you need to pass in two copies of the same tensor? If your classification network is operating on the same input tensors, you just need one input.

Comment: There are not two copies of the same tensor. As you can see, I have clearly defined two inputs that can be whatever you want. This means you can enter two different tensors to be computed by the model, what is the final goal of this question.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `tf.keras.Input` in the representation() function defines a node on the neural network's computational graph. This node represents a single input that's tied to a couple of 1D convolutional layers. Using it for two inputs at the same time doesn't make sense as there is only one path from input to output in your model definition above.
Keras uses different syntax for defining models that used shared weights and multiple inputs. [This](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/) page has good examples, and the most relevant detail in your case is "to share a layer in the functional API, call the same layer instance multiple times". In your case, you want to amend your code to actually define two input nodes and pretend like your representation model is a layer.

```
class RepresentationLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RepresentationLayer, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(300, 10, 1, 'same')
        self.conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(300, 10, 1, 'same')
    
    def __call__(self, inputs):
        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        return x

def classifier_shared_representation():
    inp1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=[100, 300])
    inp2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=[100, 300])
    rep_layer = RepresentationLayer()
    rep1 = rep_layer(inp1)
    rep2 = rep_layer(inp2)
    output = tf.keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid')(rep1+rep2)
    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inp1, inp2], outputs=[output])


model = classifier_shared_representation()
```

In the code you posted, you specify two outputs from your classification layer:

```
model = tf.keras.Model([repre.input, repre.input], cla([repre.output, repre.output]))
```

To do this in the code above, just change the tf.keras.Model call to

```
tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inp1, inp2], outputs=[output, output])
```

I'm still not sure if you want multiple outputs. It seems like your classifier() definition is just summing the representation outputs and passing them through an activation, resulting in a single output. If you do want a shared classification layer with multiple outputs, the process is the same as above.

Comment: I have used this solution before but what I want is to define the representation and the classification separately in order to have different classifiers some of them with a different number of inputs. I guess I have to define the whole "classifier_shared_representation" for each classifier.
In my code, there are not two outputs, it is just one "cla([repre.output, repre.output])" as you say it is only the summing of the inputs in the classification layer because is a toy example. Thank you for this solution, it is what I implemented for the moment.